# Will slice then append back to the same shape increase memory usage?

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.random.rand(3, 4)
x = x[1:]
x = np.append(x, np.random.rand(1, 4), axis=0)
```

The second line creates a new view of the original data, so no memory change. My question is that will the third line increase memory usage?

If `append` copies the original data, regardless of the view, and appends new data to it, it should increase memory usage.

If `append` constructs a smaller array based on both the view and the original data, and appends new data to it, it should not increase memory usage.

I am not sure which case is it.

Ultimately I want to know will the following script have memory leak?

```
x = np.random.rand(3, 4)
for _ in range(1000000):
    x = x[1:]
    x = np.append(x, np.random.rand(1, 4), axis=0)
```

Comment: `np.append` with `axis` is  just `np.concatenate`.  It makes a new array, with its own data.  In this case it makes a (3,4), with values from the (2,4) and the (1,4).  That `x[1:]` is  view of something else doesn't matter.    The original `x` array gets gc.  No 'memory leak' (we don't really have those with numpy), but repeated concatenates in a loop is time consuming, with a new array and all attendant copies each time.

Comment: Look at `x.base` at various times in your code to get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) "append does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and filled."

Comment: Don't let the assignments back to `x` confuse you.  That's a basic python assignment to a variable, and doesn't change the nature of the `numpy` operation, whether it's slicing or concatenating.  There's no in-place array operations here. `numpy` makes a `view` when it can to minimize copying (and save time), but it never changes the size of the original `base`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Python does not *"leak memory"* in the sense of other languages that allocate and de-allocate memory. Primarily because Python uses reference counting (basically deletes unused variables) for its memory management.

But in any event, one can verify the memory location and in the case of the question, its size, by using the `getsizeof()` method in the `sys` module.

so in the case of the question, you can do this:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(3, 4)

print(id(x), sys.getsizeof(x))

x = x[1:]
print(id(x), sys.getsizeof(x))

x = np.append(x, np.random.rand(1, 4), axis=0)
print(id(x), sys.getsizeof(x))
```

The result is this:

```
2258306994064 224
2258420666736 128
2258420666544 224
```

What this is telling you is that the object memory location has moved 3 times (`x` is now at the last memory id). Also you can see the sizes each time (the slice actually occupied less memory).

That is one of the nice gains in Python. Memory is handled for the user.

Finally,  in summary, the script will not leak memory.
X will be the final size of the appended list.

Comment: `id` is misleading because of address reuse, and trivial array views are new objects but use existing data. And `getsizeof` can get container sizes wrong. We know how much data the arrays use. Question is if it's the same memory block, and if not, whether the old one is recycled.

Comment: what do you propose @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні ?  i believe that at beginner level it is descriptive enough to drive the point, but would be interested to see you answer.

Comment: No, it's just fancy-looking handwaving.

Comment: so what do you suggest ?  you have said what **cannot** be done, but what **can** be done in that respect ?

Comment: A complete answer could address how views vs copies work, how these lay out in the question's code, and how python's memory management works when objects are destroyed. If this sounds like a lot, it is. The question is too broad. But what the asker really needs is addressed by the duplicates.